# Why is my mosfet driver circuit clipping lower voltages?

Tags: amplifier, mosfet-driver

How can I fix this? I've been trying for hours. I want to try and get 0-20V and 2.5A out of 0-5V input (V3). I pretty much chose a random n-channel mosfet that I thought was in spec, but I have a P30N06LE to use.

Click on image to open full resolution version.

[image: Screencap of amplifier sim]

Most recently modified circuit (visible in stackexchange too)
[image: Most recent modified circuit]

Comment: How is thing expected to work? Vout is connected permanently to 23.5V... there should not be anything at the output but this fixed 23.5V.

Comment: Haha that made me laugh out loud quite loudly. The Vout in the screencap was old and I'm actually taking the output from the mosfet source. I updated the screenshot to be accurate.

Comment: Why do you have a gain of 4.3 when you only need a gain of 4?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd really like 0-22V but I'm not sure if I can get that or not with this configuration. Lowering the gain just seems to lower the maximum output voltage, but doesn't remove the clipping. Here's a link to the LTspice schematic incase its useful: http://1drv.ms/1BpRZbC

Comment: I think I want to opamp feedback to encompass the mosfet as well, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that?

Comment: You do notice that you are clipping at 0v.  With a single ended supply that is the obvious limit on the down side.

Comment: Instead of joining the negative feedback loop onto the mosfet gate (labelled out), I linked it to Vout. Now I get the voltage going from 0-20V using a 3k resistor instead of 3k3. But if I replace in different nmos components they are clipping at 20V now, the gains seem a bit different for each one or something... why is the maximum output voltage 20V?

Comment: Some of the mosfets clip the output voltage to 18V.

Comment: Post a schematic that we can actually read.  Closing until then.

Comment: I don't think it should matter on a simulation, but try changing R7 to 750 ohms to better match the - input resistance.

Comment: Hmm you're right didn't make a difference in the simulator. In fact in the circuit that resistance comes from a DAC and is minimum 10k.

Comment: Connecting Vout directly to R1 (break the old R1 connection) is another option.

Comment: To give a better screen shot move your circuit to the far left then take a new screen shot and crop most of the right side.  That should allow a larger view to be pasted.

Comment: OK I've posted a more visible schematic.

Comment: @Olin: re "Post a schematic that we can actually read. Closing until then." -> Your ball.

Comment: The output cannot be closer to V+in than (V+ - opamp_Vout_abs_max) + Gsgsth + a bit more. The data sheet can be a bit uncertain but an LM358 cannot get closer than 2 + volts to and your MOSFET needs 1++ V gate drive so expect Voutmax to be 3 to 6V below V+. So 20V with a 23.5V supply is "lucky".

Comment: @Russell: I just got your message (Sunday morning here now), but I see there is already a accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mosfet needs at least a couple of volts on the gate before it begins to conduct anything meaningful and the signal from the op-amp will drop below this figure and turn the FET off.

One thing that you can try is connecting the feedback resistor from the source instead of the op-amp output. Unlike your previous question, in this configuration, the FET has no gain - it's just a voltage follower so it won't oscillate.

By reconnecting the feedback resistor you are ensuring "supply meets demand" where you need it - on the source.

If you have any troubles it will be because the op-amp is not a "rail-to-rail" output. For instance with your current circuit, if you measured the output from the OP-amp directly you'd see that it clips because it can't drive it's output transistors all the way to ground or the positive rail. You might get away with it though in my proposed circuit.

Comment: Hi again :) I'm basically trying to recreate the same functionality as in my previous question, but using an n-channel instead of p-channel FET. Am I going about this correctly, or should I give the FET some gain? (I don't know how exactly to do that in this configuration)

Comment: The op-amp has plenty of gain - just move the point where you take the feedback and see what happens!

Comment: See my comment on the original post - I reconnected the feedback loop so the resistor R1 is in that location. The loop now extends right through the MOSFET and I get MUCH better accuracy. However, now I'm just a bit confused about why certain MOSFET components that I substitute in now clip in the high range at either 18V or 20V.

Completely fresh idea: What if I used an LM317?

Comment: I posted a schematic of the change.

Comment: The mosfet clips because the gate voltage needs to be higher than the source voltage by a few volts. If the opamp limited at 22 volts flat out, some mosfets would clip at maybe 18 volts under load. Bigger loads means more clipping.

Comment: Great news, I built this circuit and it ran just like the simulation with no oscillation :) It could obtain about 18.3V in practice, although it does have about 0.3Vac in the output so I may need some better filtering.

Comment: If you choose a fet with a lower Vgs(threhold) parameter you might squeeze out closer to 20 volts.